# Unable to delete virtual network interface on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I ran `tcpdump` as follows.

```
tcpdump -I -l
```

Then, after a while, I hit Ctrl-C to exit, and the following error appeared at the end of the output.

```
Can't delete monitor interface mon0 (wlp3s0: nl_wait_for_ack failed adding mon0 interface: Operation not permitted).
Please delete manually.
```

So I tried to delete the interface manually with `sudo ip link delete dev mon0`, but this didn't work. I then tried, `sudo ip link set dev mon0 down`, and then I reran the previous command to delete the virtual interface, but it stilll didn't work. Instead, it prints the following error.

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

After restarting my computer, the virtual interfaces are gone; however, I don't want to have to reboot my system every time I want to delete an interface.

Does someone know what is going on, and how I can fix this issue?

**NOTE**

Some may say that this is a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326704/how-do-i-delete-virtual-interface-in-linux), but I would disagree because no posted solution there fixes my issue. In fact, it seems the author experienced the same issue, as mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326704/how-do-i-delete-virtual-interface-in-linux), but never followed up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to delete the virtual interface, so I'll post the solution here.

Basically, I was using the wrong utility. I should have been trying to delete the virtual interface with `iw`, not `ip`.

Here is the command to delete whatever virtual interface you want.

```
sudo iw dev <dev> del
```

In my case, I needed to execute the following.

```
sudo iw dev mon0 del
```